# Extracting data in SQL with newly created column with date and time

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer to extract data from database. There is a timestamp column that is in this format: 02-SEP-19 10.31.34.315000000 AM but I would like to create 2 new columns, one for the date (02/09/19) and one for the time in 24H format.

Is there a way to extract the entire table together with newly created columns? The reason why i need the 2 additional columns with Date and Time is to compare with another set of data.

This would enable me to extract data with specific date range and time. For e.g. All records from 01-SEP-19 to 30-SEP-19 and from 08:00:00 to 10:00:00.

```
Select * 
From Table 
Where CRT_DTTM > '02-SEP-19' and CRT_DTTM < '03-SEP-19'
order by CRT_DTTM ASC
```

Comment: I vote against creating separate columns for the date and time.  Just keep the `CRT_DTTM` column as it is.

Comment: Hi Tim, i would like to use the data extracted for further processing. So it will be really useful if there is an easy way to extract data together with the new columns.

Answer (score 0):

> For e.g. All records from 01-SEP-19 to 30-SEP-19 and from 08:00:00 to
>   10:00:00.

You don't need a separate column, simply include the time extraction logic within the query.It's inefficient to maintain another column to store just the time.

```
 Select * 
   From Table 
     Where CRT_DTTM >= DATE '2019-09-01' and CRT_DTTM < DATE '2019-09-30'
     AND extract(hour from CRT_DTTM) >=8 and extract(hour from CRT_DTTM) < 10
 order by CRT_DTTM ASC
```

If you want more specific time, simply use `TO_TIMESTAMP` with the start and end time you wish.

For eg:

```
WHERE CRT_DTTM >= TO_TIMESTAMP('01-SEP-2019 08:20:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
..
..
```

Comment: Hi Kaushik, thanks for your response. Sorry, was not clear in my question. I would need the additional columns so it would be simpler for me to compare with another dataset with Date and Time information.

Comment: @jason : Without sample data it's hard to tell what you're trying. But, adding another column to simply store time component is never advisable. I speak from experience.

Answer (score 0):

Adding new column(s) just because "it makes it easier to ..." seldom works out well. It has to be significantly easier when **ALL** uses are considered. Further have you considered combining the other tables columns to create an actual date or timestamp. However, sometimes there's away to have your cake and eat it too!  
Add your 2 columns, but make them VIRTUAL columns. That way nothing that currently processes the existing column needs to change and you get the date and time only columns. Downside: They are characters as ALL oracle date (timestamp) columns contains date and time components.

```
create table  atable( atable_ts timestamp); 

insert into atable values (current_timestamp);
insert into atable values (current_timestamp - interval '6' hour);
insert into atable values (current_timestamp + interval '9' hour);

select * from atable;

alter table atable add (atable_day  generated always as 
                                    (  to_char(extract(year from atable_ts) ) || '-'   
                                    || to_char(extract(month from atable_ts) ) || '-' 
                                    || to_char(extract(day from atable_ts) ) ) 
                        ,atable_tod  generated always as 
                                     ( to_char(extract(hour from atable_ts) ) || ':'   
                                    || to_char(extract(minute from atable_ts) ) || ':' 
                                    || to_char(extract(second from atable_ts) ) )
                         );        

select * from atable;
```